# How do you make this work ... and why does it not work?

Tags: elixir

I tried this below:

`iex(7)> String.split ("hello world") |> String.upcase |> Enum.join(" // ")`

and I got this :

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "HELLO WORLD"
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:112: Enumerable.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1124: Enum.reduce/3
```

Can someone who knows please enlighten me on why this does not work ?!

Comment: Not near a computer, but try `String.upcase("hello world") |> String.split |> Enum.join(" // ")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write:

```
String.upcase("hello world") |> String.split |> Enum.join(" // ")
```

Notice here two points:

1. `f(x) |> g` equals to `g(f(x))`, while `f (x) |> g` equals to `f(g(x))` (the whitespace affects operator precedence).
2. `String.split("hello world") => ["hello", "world"]` and `String.upcase(["hello", "world"])` will not work.

Comment: Fun fact: `String.upcase ("hello world") |> String.split |> Enum.join(" // ")` also works :)